# issue regarding to fetch data using sql query on 3 ignite server cluster

Tags: java, mysql, sql-server, ignite

I am using three Apache ignite server cluster and applied SQL query on same configuration and same data but some time data not get through select query,
Can any one tell me how to fix it?

1. In cluster mode all data is stored on all server side?
2. If not then how SQL query apply on that node on which data is not present ?

(I am using Apache Ignite cluster in which three server are used and on TRANSNATIONAL mode cache, applied sql query but sometime data is not fetch by the same sql query.)

Comment: You should provide more information. What is your data model? What is the query you're executing? How do you load the data and how do you execute the query? What exactly is wrong in the result? Etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. All data of Partitioned and Replicated caches resides on server nodes (on all by default). You can restrict cache to certain nodes with setting up NodeFilter in cache configuration.

   Data distribution depends on [affinity function]. By default, [RendezvousAffinityFunction] is used, it makes data distribution close to equals and reduce amount of data to be transfer when grid topology changes.
2. [Distributed sql query] in ignite run on all data nodes for caches that participate in query.

   It is possible, you get no data because you try to use joins on non-collocated data. By default, distributed joins is disabled. See [Affinity collocation] and [Distributed Joins]  docs.
3. For now, SQL layer is not transactional, so, dirty reads are possible.